# conflict between ctable and csvsimple?

Tags: pdftex, csvsimple, ctable

The following MWE produces an error upon compilation:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{ctable} 
\usepackage{csvsimple}
\begin{document}
test
\end{document}
```

The error is:

```
! Undefined control sequence.
\pgfutil@addpdfresource@extgs ...urce@extgs@plain 
                                                  {#1}
```

What is going on here, and how can it be fixed?

Comment: [Bug report filed.](https://github.com/T-F-S/csvsimple/issues/9]) Let me know if a different action is needed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not a `csvsimple` problem, but a conflict between `ctable` and `pgfrcs` which loads `pgfutil-common.tex`.

An MWE to show the error is

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{ctable}
\usepackage{pgfrcs}

\begin{document}
test
\end{document}
```

`ctable` seems to have a `tikz` detection, but fails to detect `pgf`. One gets a package error, if `tikz` is loaded after `ctable`.

A workaround is to load `tikz` additionally before `ctable`:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{ctable}
\usepackage{csvsimple}

\begin{document}
test
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

It's caused by line 237 in `pgfutil-common.tex`, which is surrounded by some unsure comments. I could solve the problem by adding:

```
\makeatletter\def\pgf@sys@addpdfresource@extgs@plain#1{}\makeatother
```

to the preamble; but then — keep fingers crossed...